# Having trouble understanding this syntax for R

Tags: r

I have been given following code for R, but I am having trouble understanding what it is doing. In fact I can not even run it in R because of its syntax. I assume the syntax is for lower level code behind R. If someone could help explain what's happening here and translate this into executable R code that would be very helpful.

```
soft_thresholding = function(x,a){
  result  a)]  a)] - a
  result[which(x &lt; -a)] = x[which(x &lt; -a)] + a
  return(result)}
```

Comment: can you check  whether it works `result  a)]  a)] - a` there is some issue in the syntax.  also the `&lt` may be this is a copying issue

Comment: @akrun Yes, there are multiple issues just copying this into R. It is given as a function here. So I'm not making typos. https://www.r-bloggers.com/classification-from-scratch-penalized-lasso-logistic-5-8/

Comment: could be that it is copied there incorrectly

Comment: If one uses wordpress and add code, then `x <- a` will look like `x &lt; -a`. Check this [URL](https://r-posts.com/)  that confirms this assumption

Comment: `result[which(x &lt; -a)] = x[which(x &lt; -a)] + a` must be `result[which(x <- a)] = x[which(x <- a)] + a`

Comment: Thank you @SidharthMacherla that is incredibly helpful. Please let me know if you have any ideas about `result a)] a)] - a`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a summary of the findings. This is not a definite answer but could help the questioner.

1. If one uses wordpress, then x <- a will look like x < -a. Check this URL that confirms this assumption
2. Upon further online search with the function name in the question "soft_thresholding", shows that this function is probably attempting to do soft thresholding defined [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15464/wavelet-thresholding).
3. Some more online searching about soft thresholding lands on a CRAN package that is present [here](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RGCCA).
4. Further deepdive into the r folder in the package binaries shows the following.

```
soft.threshold <- function(x,sumabs=1) 
return(soft(x, BinarySearch(x,sumabs)))
```

5. The function above seems very close to the code in the question.
6. Furthermore, the soft.threshold function uses another internal function BinarySearch that looks like this.

```
BinarySearch <-
function(argu,sumabs){
  if(norm2(argu)==0 || sum(abs(argu/norm2(argu)))<=sumabs) return(0)
  lam_max = max(abs(argu))
  lam1      <- 0
  lam2      <- lam_max
  iter <- 1
  while(iter < 500){
    su <- soft(argu,(lam1+lam2)/2)
    if(sum(abs(su/norm2(su)))<sumabs){
      lam2 <- (lam1+lam2)/2
    } else {
      lam1 <- (lam1+lam2)/2
    }
    if((lam2-lam1)/lam1 < 1e-10){
      if (lam2 != lam_max){
        return(lam2)
      }else{
        return(lam1)
      }
    }
    iter <- iter+1
  }
  warning("Didn't quite converge")
  return((lam1+lam2)/2)
}
```

7. This recursive research leads one to believe that the function is perhaps attempting to mimic the function soft.threshold in the CRAN package "RGCCA"

*Hope it helps*